# How to implement properly an inline function in the device that returns a vector to another device function?

Tags: cuda, gpgpu, thrust

I want to implement properly an inlined device function that fill out  a vector of dynamic size and return the filled vector like:

```
__device__  inline   thrust::device_vector<double> make_array(double zeta, int l)
{
  thrust::device_vector<double> ret;
  int N =(int)(5*l+zeta); //the size of the array  will depend on l and zeta, in a complex way...
  // Make sure of sufficient memory allocation
  ret.reserve(N);
  // Resize array
  ret.resize(N);
  //fill it:
  //for(int i=0;i<N;i++)
  // ...;
  return ret;
}
```

My goal is to use the content of the returned vector in another device function like:

```
__device__  inline double use_array(double zeta,int l)
{
  thrust::device_vector<double> array = make_array(zeta, l);

  double result = 0;

  for(int i=0; i<array.size(); i++)
    result += array[i];

  return result;
}
```

How can I do it properly? my feeling is that a thrust vector is designed for this type of task, but I want to do it properly. What is the standard CUDA approach to this task?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`thrust::device_vector` is [not usable in device code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24989180/using-thrustdevice-vector-in-device-code).

However you can return a pointer to [a dynamically allocated area](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#dynamic-global-memory-allocation-and-operations), like so:

```
#include <assert.h>

template <typename T>
__device__  T* make_array(T zeta, int l)
{
  int N =(int)(5*l+zeta); //the size of the array  will depend on l and zeta, in a complex way...
  T *ret = (T *)malloc(N*sizeof(T));
  assert(ret != NULL);  // error checking

  //fill it:
  //for(int i=0;i<N;i++)
  // ret[i] = ...;
  return ret;
}
```

The `inline` keyword should not be necessary.  The [compiler will aggressively inline functions wherever possible](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#noinline-and-forceinline).

Comment: Is possible to free the memory allocated for  the array, ret,  from another device function once the  computation is ready?

Comment: yes, as long as you are appropriately careful in usage, you can use in-kernel `free`.  This is covered in the [documentation](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#dynamic-global-memory-allocation-and-operations).

Comment: Thanks a lot for your advice.