# CUDA - How to return results of unknown size

Tags: c, arrays, cuda, combinations

I'm passing a large 2D array (in C) to the device and determining all possible combinations.  For example:

```
A = 
id  val1 val2
1   100  200
2   400  800

Combination = 
id1  id2  sumval1  sumval2
1    2    500      1000
```

Because of the size of the original array, storing and returning all possible combinations would not be possible.  I would like to return all combinations where sumval1 > 500 and sumval2 > 1000.

How can I return just this subset of combinations to the host to be written to a file; given that I won't know how many combinations meet the conditions?

Answer (score 3):

Some possible approaches:

1. Allocate (from the host) whatever space you have left in GPU memory for a buffer.  If you exceed that, you weren't going to be able to pass all the combinations back in a single transfer anyway. (Which may lead you to use the solution proposed by mtk99).
2. Dynamically allocate space as you need it on the device using in-kernel `malloc`.  At the completion of your combination-creation, collect all the individual combinations into a single buffer created with `malloc`.  Then pass the total size of this buffer, and the pointer to this buffer, back to the host.  The host then allocates a new buffer of that size using `cudaMalloc`, and launches a kernel to copy the data from the buffer created with `malloc` to the buffer created with `cudaMalloc`.  At the completion of this copy-kernel, the host can transfer the data back to the host from the buffer created with `cudaMalloc`.

I would suggest that 1 is probably the best approach without knowing anything else about what you are trying to do.  In kernel `malloc` is not particularly fast when allocating large numbers of small allocations.  Also, when using in-kernel `malloc`, note the default size limitation (8MB) which can be increased.

Comment: I like the paging idea. I will allocate array R for the results, but how should I index the array? In C I would i++ every time a result is entered. Will I run into issues with all threads using the same i?

Comment: Yes, if you have multiple threads trying to update a single buffer, there will be issues.  My answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21786495/cuda-kernel-returning-vectors/21788662#21788662) may be useful for having multiple threads push data into a single buffer.

Answer (score 0):

You can page the results:

- Create a fix result array (let's say Z items).
- Return not only the results but the point where you stopped (last_id1, last_id2).
- On the next call pass a new starting point (start_id1, start_id2) based on your last result.

You can use streams in order to keep the GPU loaded.

Based on this, you could even distribute the calculation using several GPUs.

Comment: I like the paging idea.  I will allocate array R for the results, but how should I index the array?  In C I would i++ every time a result is entered.  Will I run into issues with all threads using the same i?

Comment: You should do stream compaction, have a look at thrust::remove_if. Generate as many combinations as you can fit in your output array. Maybe you need the input to be a texture, so you can use the values in your predicate without copying them to the output. Run stream compaction and return last_id1 and lastid_2. Call the kernel many times with different starting points as you progress through the data.